# Dynamic columns col1 Col2 Col3 Col4

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in that there are 4 columns , columns might get added or deleted on regular interval. I need a dynamic query which handle the columns on run time basis and perform a calculation.

Below are my structure of my table along with sample of records.

```
ID,   col1,          col2,            col3,             col4
1  '2016-08-09'     '2016-08-09'    '2016-08-09'     '2016-08-09'
2  '2016-08-10'     '2016-08-10'    '2016-08-13'     '2016-08-04'
```

I want result in which my date difference should come in each columns and there should one total columns should append which give total count of those columns for particular ID. Result set should be like below.

```
ID  col1  Col2  Col3 Col4  Total
1    6     6     6    6     24
2.   6     7     8    8     29
```

Comment: How do you get that expected output from the sample data...?

Comment: Explain your Date Diff calculation.

Comment: Your Date Diff for ID looks like datediff(dd,coln,getdate()) but ID 2 does not follow the same pattern

Answer (score 1):

Tested, works well. :)

```
--create table structure
create table #test1 (ID int, col1 date, col2 date, col3 date, col4 date)
go

--insert sample data
insert #test1 
select 1,  '2016-08-09',     '2016-08-09',    '2016-08-09',     '2016-08-09'
union all
select 2,  '2016-08-10',     '2016-08-10',    '2016-08-13',     '2016-08-04' 
union all
select 3,  '2016-08-10',     '2016-08-10',    NULL,     '2016-08-04' 


--below is solution
with cte_test1 (id, dif1, dif2, dif3, dif4) as
(
    select  id, 
            datediff(day, col1, getdate()) as dif1,
            datediff(day, col2, getdate()) as dif2,
            datediff(day, col3, getdate()) as dif3,
            datediff(day, col4, getdate()) as dif4
    from #test1
)
select id,dif1,dif2,dif3,dif4,ISNULL(dif1,0)+ISNULL(dif2,0)+ISNULL(dif3,0)+ISNULL(dif4,0) as difTotal
from cte_test1
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: OP was looking for dynamic

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. To be frank, i am not sure what the "deleting and adding columns" mean here. I suppose by deleting columns, the OP means set it as null.

Comment: You may very well be correct.  My understanding is columns not rows.  That said, I have a solution for him, but he never responded to my questions.   Moving on... cheers